# Terraform how to trim a string after the 3rd "-"

Tags: terraform

I want to trim the first part of the string after the 3rd "-"
For example

str = "hello-welcome-to-new-terraform"

output = "new-terraform"

str = "this-is-an-example-of-things"

output = "example-of-things"

str = "terraform-is-a-thing"

output = "thing"

Ideally if we can just have that done in 1 line that'd be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `regex` for that:

```
regex("(?:[^-]*-){2}(.*)", "hello-welcome-to-new-terraform")
```

gives

```
new-terraform
```

Answer (score 0):

And without using regex which I dislike for being cryptic:

```
str="this-is-an-example-of-things"

out="-".join(str.split("-")[3:])
```

It splits the string at the - to form a list, discarts the first three and rejoins the list to a string

Comment: does [3:] works in terraform?

Comment: @minnie - no... I think this guy copy pasted some python and thought it'd work. correct syntax is `join("-", slice(split("-", <list>), 3, length(split("-", <list>))))`